# SQL - Sum issue with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

I am new to SQL.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    E.name AS Employee_Name, 
    P.HoursWorked AS Hours_Worked, 
    DATENAME(month, C.dayid) AS Month_Name
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN employeepaysummary P ON E.employeeId = P.employeeId
INNER JOIN CalendarDay C ON P.dayid = C.dayid ;
```

returns below result:

```
Employee_Name   Hours_Worked    Month_Name
John, Sturgis       6           January
John, Sturgis       8           January
John, Sturgis       8           January
Sheldon, Cooper     7           January
Sheldon, Cooper     6           January
```

How can I sum (hours_worked) column?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use [SUM](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/) aggregation function:

```
SELECT 
    E.name AS Employee_Name, 
    SUM(P.HoursWorked) AS Hours_Worked, 
    DATENAME(month, C.dayid) AS Month_Name
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN employeepaysummary P ON E.employeeId = P.employeeId
INNER JOIN CalendarDay C ON P.dayid = C.dayid 
GROUP BY 
    E.employeeId, E.name, DATENAME(month, C.dayid);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You just need a group by

```
   select E.name as Employee_Name, sum(P.HoursWorked) as Hours_Worked, 
from employee E
INNER JOIN employeepaysummary P ON E.employeeId = P.employeeId
INNER JOIN CalendarDay C ON P.dayid = C.dayid group by Employee_Name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please tag your DB. But below query should work just fine. You need to use `sum()` and `group by`:

```
select E.name as Employee_Name, sum(P.HoursWorked) as Hours_Worked, 
DATENAME(month, C.dayid) AS Month_Name
from employee E
INNER JOIN employeepaysummary P ON E.employeeId = P.employeeId
INNER JOIN CalendarDay C ON P.dayid = C.dayid 
group by E.name,DATENAME(month, C.dayid);
```

Comment: You query can be wrong in case 2 different employees  with same name

Comment: Thank you so much.